# Docker entrypoint and cmd together

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I try to setup a Docker with both entrypoint and cmd.

```sh
FROM debian:stretch
RUN apt-get update && \
apt install gnupg ca-certificates -y 
RUN echo "deb http://repo.aptly.info/ squeeze main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aptly.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 9E3E53F19C7DE460
RUN apt update && apt install aptly -y
ADD aptly.conf /etc/aptly.conf
ADD start.sh .
VOLUME ["/aptly"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
CMD ["aptly", "api", "serve"]
```

But entrypoint script is not stopping...
The cmd command is not launching

Here my script :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e 
init_aptly() {  
  #import pgp key
  #create nginx root folder in /aptly
  su -c "mkdir -p /aptly/.aptly/public"
  echo "12"
  #initialize repository
  #aptly create repo doze-server -   distribution="stable"
}
#check for first run
if [ ! -e /aptly/.aptly/public ]; then
  init_aptly
  echo "13"
fi
echo "14"
```

The script always echo 14, I would like only one and then, execute the cmd command from dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image has an `ENTRYPOINT`, as other answers here have noted, that is the only command the container runs, and the `CMD` is passed to it as additional arguments.  Also see the section [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation.

This means, in the entrypoint wrapper script, you need to actually run the command you're passed.  The usual approach here is to end your script with the shell construct `exec "$@"`, like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# ... do startup-time setup ...
# ...then run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Note that this works however the command part is provided.  If for example you `docker run your-image some-other-command`, then it will run the entrypoint wrapper script from the image, but at the end it will run `some-other-command` instead of the `CMD` from the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 70):

When you use both entrypoint and command, the command section will be appended to entrypoint executable as arguments. Thus in your case:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
CMD ["aptly", "api", "serve"]
```

Is equivalent to running:

```
ENTRYPOINT["/start.sh", "aptly", "api", "serve"]
```

Comment: You can combine executable like bash scripts `CMD ./start.sh && aptly api serve`

Comment: This is so intuitive of course.... Strong negative feelings for whoever dev implemented it like so!

Comment: This ans saved me even in 2019

Comment: Weird... behavior?

Comment: I must be blind but I couldn't seem to see where in the documentation it explains this. Can someone please put a link to the docs showing this?

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer the first syntax over the second? E.g. could it affect how command overwrite (while running the container) applies?

Comment: @ADJenks Entrypoint example in docker reference (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example)

Answer (score 26):

One important note, since nobody else has mentioned it: in order to use `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together, you need to specify both in the array format. Doing something like this **WILL NOT WORK**:

```
ENTRYPOINT ./my_script.sh
CMD echo "hello world"
```

In the code above, `./my_script.sh` will be called, but `CMD` will not be passed in.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from hours of debugging!

Answer (score 6):

Can't tell much without knowing what the entrypoint does, but essentially this is what you are doing with this combination of entrypoint and cmd:

```
/start.sh aptly api serve
```

If you are after simply starting your server you can simply do something like this (valid path to the `aptly` executable may be neccessary):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["aptly"]
CMD ["api", "serve"]
```

Unless you are doing much more than just running an executable there's no need for an entrypoint.

Comment: No need cmd, just ENTRYPOINT [/start.sh aptly api serve]?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow the default arguments of entrypoint (provided in CMD) to be replaced by the arguments provided in `docker run`.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
CMD ["aptly", "api", "serve"]
```

The following will append the arguments provided in `docker run` to the entrypoint after the last argument. In order to override the entrypoint and its arguments at once you will need to explicitly use the `--entrypoint` flag:

```bash
ENTRYPOINT["/start.sh", "aptly", "api", "serve"]
```